# PKCS #5 padding with m2crypto

Tags: python, aes, m2crypto, pkcs#5

Is there any way to use PKCS #5 padding with AES CBC in m2crypto? Can't seem to find one too easily. Is there any python library that can do this?

Or do I need to do it manually? If so, are there any resources on doing this?

Comment: Did you try to simply give some data to the library for encryption? Does it use another padding by default?

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't work for what I need. It is possible to turn some sort of padding on by using padding=1 or padding=0 to turn it off, but the m2crypto docs are so bad I have no idea what this actually does. I get a bad decrypt message if padding=1 for both encrypt and decrypt, though oddly it doesn't complain if I use padding=0 to decrypt, but padding=1 to encrypt, though it always seems to decrypt to a different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much thrashing through OpenSSL docs, it looks like PKCS #5 is the padding scheme it uses. Well, the OpenSSL docs aren't that great either so I'm still only 90% sure of this.